# Label text and UIImage

Tags: ios, swift

My app design is simple. I consists of a UIImageView, UILabel, and UIButton.

When the button is pressed I want the image to change AND the label to change. The catch, I need the label to match what is in the image. (Example: picture of a cat is displayed, the label reads "Cat".)

Is there a way for me to display the image file name as the label text? If not, how would I go about making this happen?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you set the image, you can update the label accordingly.

If your image is in your Assets, then you can simply use UIImage(named:) method, giving it the file name of your image.  Then you can set the label.text property to the same value.  See example below:

```
let fileName = "Cat.jpeg"
myImageView.image = UIImage(named: fileName)
myLabel.text = fileName
```